# The Customers - Rebus puzzle

Tags: rebus, english

Solve the following rebus puzzle:

```
    __________________________________
   |                                  |
   |                        Customer  |
   |                        CUSTOMER  |
   |                        customer  |
   |                        CuStOmEr  |
   |                        cUsToMeR  |
   |__________________________________|
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe..

> The customers are always right

Comment: Even if the customers are always right, it doesn't explain why each customer is written differently - it seems as if the numerous spellings is an misleading complication.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to luxmi's answer following can be said too

> Each customer is different

Comment: No, your answer would not fit with the bounding box.